# Spring OAuth2 resource server with Google Authorization server

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2resourceserver

I am trying to implement a simple Spring OAuth2 resource server using google as OAuth server.

Basically, I've been following guides like this one [spring-oauth2-with-google](https://medium.com/geekculture/springboot-api-authentication-using-oauth2-with-google-655b8759f0ac)

application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: *******.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret:********_
            scope:
              - email
              - profile
              - openid
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public void getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        System.out.println("Id: " + id);
    }
}
```

I am able to get the google JWT through postman as described in the guide, but no matter how hard I try, when I try to consume my end point, through postman, the response is always 401. I have already tried to set a space between the Bearer keyword and token_id.

Error in postman:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid token", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

but if i review the token in [google token info](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=) the result seems ok:

```
  "issued_to": "263667859573-jve8vplquh7qn4ft7aaj1t1m9boaq5d6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "audience": "263667859573-jve8vplquh7qn4ft7aaj1t1m9boaq5d6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id": "112897290372529438679",
  "scope": "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "expires_in": 3296,
  "email": "javier@email.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "access_type": "online"
```

Comment: How do you use the token in Postman exactly? As a side note, you might not need the `client` properties, unless you serve Thymeleaf pages or consume Google APIs using client credentials (not forwarding user's token).

Comment: Just a GET to http://localhost:8080/user/1 plus setting oauth2 authrization: Auth URL, Access Token URL, client ID and client Secret, once you get the token then it is used in the auth header automatically

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, the access-token you get from Google is just not a JWT but an opaque token, in which case configuring your resource-server with a JWT decoder won't work. try to "open" one of your access-tokens in a tool like https://jwt.io to be sure.

I couldn't find a standard introspection endpoint for such Google opaque tokens, just https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo to which you can submit `access_token` as request param. If token is valid, you'll get claims in response. So, you could actually configure your resource-server with token introspection (instead of JWT decoder), providing your own token introspector to call the tokeninfo endpoint, check the response and either throw an exception or return an `Authentication` of your choice.

```java
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().introspector(...);
```

But this is quite some work and introspection is far less efficient than decoding JWTs (first requires to submit token to Google for each and every incoming request on your resource server, when fetching public key only once for all request is enough for second).

It is likely that Google just doesn't want us to use their authorization-servers for our own resource-server except for a few limited cases (and I'm not sure which ones).

An alternative for you is using another authorization-server capable of federating "social" identities (Google, of course, but also Facebook, Github, etc.). Plenty do so: [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/downloads) is a famous on premise solution, but if you don't want to bother at maintaining an authorization-server yourself, you could have a look at SaaS like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) (which has a free tier). Those two are just my current preferred in a galaxy of solutions, just search for "OIDC authorization-server" and choose your own.

Comment: "It is likely that Google just doesn't want us to use their authorization-servers for our own resource-server" that's one of my fears, that this solution is conceptually not so right and google token should be used just to consume google APIs

Comment: Your response is aligned with this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257316/2549615 , I'll try to implement the introspector

Comment: As explained in my answer, this more of a hack. You should really consider spinning a Keycloak instance (or opening an Auth0 instance) and stick with JWT decoder