# Spring cloud gateway does not redirect to authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, spring-cloud-gateway

I am setting up spring cloud gateway application as an `OAuth2` client. In the security config class I set up some whitelist paths. If any unauthorized user wants to access any secured path, he/she should be **redirected** to google login consent page automatically. But, in my case this ***auto redirection is not happening***. Rather upon accessing any secured path I got a `401` error.

Bellow is my sample code -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SsoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public class WelcomeController {

        @GetMapping
        public String openPath() {
            return "this is open path";
        }

        @GetMapping("/secured")
        public String securedPath() {
            return "Accessing secured path";
        }
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
                        .pathMatchers("/", "/*.css", "/*.js", "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
                .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: #client_id#
            client-secret: #secret#
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/google"
server:
  port: 9999
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.0")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

I have tried following thing -

1. Added `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on `SecurityWebFilterChain` bean.

> gives HTTP ERROR 401 on accessing secured path, doesn't redirect to login page

2. Removed `@Configuration` annotation from the `SecurityConfig` class

> solves the problem of redirection but all whitelist paths became **restricted** (I wonder why)!
> 3. Removed `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` and kept `@Configuration`
> gives HTTP ERROR 401 on accessing secured path, doesn't redirect to login page.
> 4. Added `redirection-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/google"` at application.yml
> gives HTTP ERROR 401 on accessing secured path, doesn't redirect to login page.

In scenario 1, 3 if I manually hit `/oauth2/authorization/google`, it redirects me to the login page.

I have tried to implement the same thing with a `spring-boot-starter-web` application; **EVERYTHING WORKS AS EXPECTED**.

#### update

[apparently not. I didn't add the `authenticationEntryPoint` at `spring-boot-web` application. That's why this app was acting as expected as @ch4mp pointed out]

Any idea, why this is happening on `spring-cloud-gateway` application and what can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly ask for 401 (instead of 302 which is the default for OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login`).

Try to remove

```java
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling -> exceptionHandling
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))
```

Comment: so, to initiate a login from SPA I need to redirect the request to `/oauth2/authorization/google` on a `/login` request? Is that how the flow should work?

Comment: If your SPA is authorized with sessions (and it should), yes.

Comment: By the way, you may find [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) useful

Comment: There is a tab dedicated in my browser for this link :D, I've been following this for couple of months.

Comment: In my current project I need to use google as auth-server. We have an organizational gsuit account. So, only employee of our org can get authorized. To get things going, I've created two basic project to test the TokenRelay filter. at the resource server end I've set `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri:` and  `.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` in the `SecurityFilterChain`. Despite getting authorized by google auth server I am getting a 401 while accessing the resouce-server through cloud-gateway.

Comment: I found [your answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74538964/spring-oauth2-resource-server-with-google-authorization-server?rq=2]) very helpful to get the scenario. But I am out of soln right now.

Comment: `TokenRelay` is for OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login()`, has your gateway should probably be, when REST APIs behind the gateway are configured with `oauth2ResourceServer()`. Is it exactly your setup? Do you know if Google delivers you JWTs (have you submitted some tokens to [https://jwt.io](https://jwt.io) for instance)?

Comment: yes, that's exactly my set up. the token google sends back is `opaque` not jwt [as per the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254326/spring-boot-authorization-server-google-oauth2-openid-connect-should-work-with/71257316?noredirect=1#comment137087349_71257316). I tried performing those extra steps and it works but I really don't want to put these extra codes in each of my services unless I have to.

Comment: As explained in the answer, the problem is not the extra code, it is the very bad efficiency of introspection, and even worse in that case: using user-info as introspection endpoint. This really is a worst practice and you should be using an intermediate authorization server issuing JWTs and with "Login with Google" feature. In that particular case were you only want social login (and not your own login, registration forms, etc.), `spring-authorization-server` is not too complicated to setup. Keycloak and cloud service like Auth0 still have my preference, thaugh.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I am leaning towards using Keycloak and setting up google as Idp on it. This brings the following question - is possible to configure keycloak to redirect unauthenticated user straight to google authentication page? I don't want to have the keycloak login page in the middle.

Comment: Yes. You send `kc_idp_hint=google` as request parameter with the authorization request